# Append a div using jquery append method on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

It may be very silly question, I am new in javascript ,I Making a gallery using  http://photoswipe.com/  js library ,I  download  js library  from official site , I used  given example index.html page 
Normal working  fine. But my problem when I append  div  `$('.gallery-row').append('<div class="gallery-item"><a href="images/full/003.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/003.jpg" alt="Image 003" /></a></div>');`  on   `<div class="gallery-row"></div>` using jquery append method  from load function.
My problem :  image show but when I  click on the image then it not open  with swipe div .
I waste my whole day but didn't get anything.

my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>PhotoSwipe</title>
  <meta name="author" content="Code Computerlove -  http://www.codecomputerlove.com/"  />
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,  user-scalable=0;" name="viewport" />
  <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="photoswipe.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/simple-inheritance.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="code-photoswipe-1.0.11.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Set up PhotoSwipe with all anchor tags in the Gallery container 
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
        Code.photoSwipe('a', '#Gallery');
      }, false);
    function load(){
      //append div from this function 
      $('.gallery-row').append('<div class="gallery-item"><a href="images/full /003.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/003.jpg" alt="Image 003" /></a></div>');
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onLoad="load()">
    <div id="Header">
      <a href="http://www.codecomputerlove.com"><img   src="images/codecomputerlovelogo.gif" width="230" height="48" alt="Code Computerlove"  /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="MainContent">
      <div class="page-content">
        <h1>PhotoSwipe</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="Gallery">
        <div class="gallery-row">
          <!--
            <div class="gallery-item"><a href="images/full/001.jpg"><img  src="images/thumb/001.jpg" alt="Image 001" /></a></div>
            <div class="gallery-item"><a href="images/full/002.jpg"><img  src="images/thumb/002.jpg" alt="Image 002" /></a></div>
            <div class="gallery-item"><a href="images/full/003.jpg"><img  src="images/thumb/003.jpg" alt="Image 003" /></a></div>
          -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing the `append` in the `DOMContentLoaded` handler, before you call `Code.photoSwipe`. Also, jQuery provides a shorter way to write this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.gallery-row').append('<div class="gallery-item"><a href="images/full /003.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/003.jpg" alt="Image 003" /></a></div>');
    Code.photoSwipe('a', '#Gallery');
});
</script>
```

When you do this, remove `onload="load()"` from your `<body>` tag.

Comment: I'll just note that I tried making a fiddle, but at least the photoSwipe script used in their demo page uses things like `live()` and `$.browser` with jQuery 1.5.2, and the site says that a new version is under development. I didn't test downloading the script to see if I got an updated version or not, but it still seems like the plugin is old and outdated. Just saying ?

Comment: thanx for reply  finally its working that i want thank u soooooooo much :)

Comment: @Barmar my another question : when we click on image, Image open on PhotoSwipe  div . my question how can get the url of the image on this div.

Comment: I don't know offhand, that seems specific to PhotoSwipe, which I've never heard of before.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you need to do this :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

        Code.photoSwipe('a', '#Gallery');

    }, false);
```

After the **append**

After some [Test](http://jsfiddle.net/HgJ33/1/), **DOMContentLoaded** is fired **before onload**

Comment: It doesn't matter where you put that, because it runs when the DOM is loaded, not when you add it.

Comment: After some [Test](http://jsfiddle.net/HgJ33/1/), DOMContentLoaded is fired before onload

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's the extra space in the href for your a tag?  Try changing "images/full /003.jpg" to "images/full/003.jpg"